# react js breadcrumbs

Tags: reactjs, react-router, breadcrumbs

In my reactJS application with react router I am trying to make dynamic breadcrumbs.

I tried this:

```
const Breadcrumbs = () => <Route path="*" render={props => {
    let parts = props.location.pathname.split("/");
    const place = parts[parts.length-1];
    parts = parts.slice(1, parts.length-1);
    return <p>{parts.map(crumb)}/{place}</p>}} />;

const crumb = (part, partIndex, parts) => {
    const path = ['', ...parts.slice(0, partIndex+1)].join("/");
    return <Link key={path} to={path} >{part}</Link>};
```

but I only got a single `/`.

Maybe it's because my url has a `#`in the url? (ie `http://localhost:8080/#/products/`)

What could be a good solution for simple breadcrumbs?

Thanks in advance

UPDATE:

```
<Provider store={store}>
                <AppContainer>
                    <Router history={history}>
    <div>
                            <div className={to.topBar}>
                                <TopBarHelper changeRole={this.changeRole} currentRole={this.state.currentRole} users={this.state.users}/>
                            </div>
                            <div className={css.sidebararound}>
                                <div className={css.sidebar}>
                                    <ul>
                                        <li><NavLink to="/dashboard" activeClassName={css.activeSidebar} className="fa fa-bars fa-2x"/>
                                            <ul className={css.SubMenu}>
                                                <li><NavLink to="/dashboard" activeClassName={css.activeSidebar} aria-hidden="true">{t('sidebar:dashboard.tooltip')}</NavLink></li>
                                            </ul>
                                        </li>
```

[...]

```
<ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
                                <MuiThemeProvider muiTheme={amTheme}>
                                    <div className={i.content}>
                                        {this.props.loaded ?
                                            <Switch>
                                                <Route path="/folders" currentRole={this.state.currentRole} component={Folders}/>
                                                    <Route exact path="/" component={props => <DashboardRoutes {...props} currentRole={this.state.currentRole} users={this.state.users} client={this.state.clientId}/>}/>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps you could use `window.location.hash` to simplify extraction of the url's path parts?

So, something along these lines:

```
const Breadcrumbs = () => <Route path="*" render={ props => {

    const hash = window.location.hash
    const parts = hash.split('/').filter(part => part.indexOf('#') === -1) // Removes first # part
    let path = ''

    return <p>{ parts.map((part, index) => {

      // Append part to current path
      path += '/' + part 

      return <Link key={index} to={path}>{part}</Link>    
    }) }
    </p>
}} />;
```

Comment: Thanks, I got this: Cannot read property 'split' of undefined

Comment: output is `<p><a href="#/"></a></p>`

Comment: okay that looks better, maybe need to give some more requirements ;) 

result is now `<p><a href="#/products">products</a><a href="#/products/edit">edit</a><a href="#/products/edit/20">20</a></p>` 

That looks good, Thanks. Is there a possibility to change the names automatically? in my navigation bar those are namend different. But Now we only use the URL as name and not the give ones.

Comment: when I add your Filter to the previous solution I got the same solution: `.filter(part => part.indexOf('#') === -1) // Removes first # part`

Comment: @Felix great to hear that it's working! Okay sure - this would involve getting the data from elsewhere in your app, and using that for rendering the name labels - are those navigaition bar labels generated from state in a redux store?

Comment: That doesn't show how you generated the labels for your navigation bar - if I undertstand your requirements correctly, that's what you're needing to do? Can you show how you render each link for your navigation bar?

Comment: The labels for the navgation are set hard coded like this `<li><NavLink to="/dashboard" activeClassName={css.activeSidebar} aria-hidden="true">{t('sidebar:dashboard.tooltip')}</NavLink></li>`
` Can I pass the label some where useful in the props?

Comment: This is the nav link label, correct? `{t('sidebar:dashboard.tooltip')}`